# How to use other struct methods from other files in Golang

Tags: go

I have a file called login.go and account.go

In login.go

```
func (api *ApiResource) test() {
   fmt.Println("Works!")
}
```

In account.go I have:

```
func main () {
   Res := new(ApiResource)
   Res.test()
}
```

Buit I'm getting `undefined:test` error.

They both use `package main` and are on same `src/` folder

What do I need to fix here?

Comment: Using IntelliJ go plugin

Comment: Not familiar with it, but maybe try to run it from the command line or build it first then run the executable.

Comment: `Res` is a local variable and should be written in lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used `go run` then you must pass both files to like `go run login.go account.go`.

Comment: How do I do this with Intelli J Go Plugin?

Comment: I don't use that, so no idea.

Comment: I'm now trying to pass this into Post request `resp, err := http.Post(url, "text/plain", bytes.NewReader(xmlTmpl))` How can I parse this into `[]byte` correctly?